# Control color, fill and line type in ggplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have data of two model results with variation presented as shaded quantiles and for each model a reference benchmark without variation. See the example data here:

```
# create data
y <- 1+0.1*c(0:29)
r1 <- runif(30,0.8,1.2)
mydata0 <- data.frame(model = "model1",scenario="a_sc1", year = c(2022:2051), q9 = y+2*r1,
                     q7=y+r1, q5=y+r1-1,q3=y-r1,q1=y-2*r1,bench= r1)

mydata1 <- mydata0
mydata1[,4:9] <- r1+mydata1[,4:9]
mydata1$model <- "model2"

mydata <- rbind(mydata0, mydata1)
```

I plot is in the following way, which is what I need, but the legend is missing the benchmark with line type.

```
library(ggplot2)
col2 <- c("darkred","steelblue")
col2f <- c("magenta","green")

ggplot(data=mydata, aes(x=year, group=model)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=q1 , ymax=q9,fill=model),  linetype=0, alpha=0.2) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=q3 , ymax=q7,fill=model),  linetype=0, alpha=0.2) +
  geom_line(aes(x=year, y=q5 ,color=model), linetype=1, size=1.3)+
  geom_line(aes(x=year, y=bench ,color=model), linetype=2, size=1.3)+
  scale_color_manual(values = col2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = col2f)+
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(1,2)) +
  labs( y = "var [mg/l]", x="") +
  theme_light() +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 18),axis.text=element_text(colour="black",size=20),legend.text=element_text(size=22))
```

<[image: models and benchmark 1]>

I arrange the data in a long format and plot as follows:

```
# second trail: long data
mydata2 <- rbind(mydata[,-9], data.frame(model=mydata$model,scenario="bench",year=mydata$year,q9=NA,q7=NA,q5=mydata$bench,q3=NA,q1=NA))
  
  ggplot(data=mydata2, aes(x=year)) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=q1 , ymax=q9,fill=model),  linetype=0, alpha=0.2, na.rm = TRUE) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=q3 , ymax=q7,fill=model),  linetype=0, alpha=0.2, na.rm = TRUE) +
    geom_line(aes(x=year, y=q5 ,color=model, linetype=scenario), size=1.3)+
    scale_color_manual(values = col2) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = col2f)+
    labs( y = "var [mg/l]", x="") +
    theme_light() +
    theme(text = element_text(size = 18),axis.text=element_text(colour="black",size=20),legend.text=element_text(size=22))
```

<[image: models and benchmark 2]>
Now I do have the legend of the benchmark  - the linetype is correct, but the coloring is missing.
I did not succeed adding it. Appreciate any ideas.

***** EDIT ******

I add here a graphicly edited image of how I want it to appear. Seems to me that my first approach would be better (not in long format) but how do I add the legend?
[image: model and benchmark - desired]

Answer (score 1):

If you want both the linetype and the color of your lines to be displayed in the legend then one option would be to map the interaction of `model` and `scenario` on the `color` and `linetype` aesthetics, which however requires to set a manual palettes taking the interaction into account:

```
library(ggplot2)

pal_color <- rep(col2, each = 2)
pal_lty <- rep(c("solid", "dashed"), 2)

names(pal_color) <- names(pal_lty) <- c("model1.a_sc1", "model1.bench", "model2.a_sc1", "model2.bench")

ggplot(data = mydata2, aes(x = year)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = q1, ymax = q9, fill = model), linetype = 0, alpha = 0.2, na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = q3, ymax = q7, fill = model), linetype = 0, alpha = 0.2, na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_line(aes(
    x = year, y = q5,
    color = paste(model, scenario, sep = "."),
    linetype = paste(model, scenario, sep = ".")
  ), size = 1.3) +
  scale_color_manual(values = pal_color) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = pal_lty) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = col2f) +
  labs(y = "var [mg/l]", x = "") +
  theme_light() +
  theme(
    text = element_text(size = 18),
    axis.text = element_text(colour = "black", size = 20),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 22)
  )
```

[image]

**UPDATE** Based on the edit containing an image of your desired result we have to do some adjustments, basically a mix of your original and my approach. First, stick with `color=model` so that we get a color/fill legend displaying both the ribbons and the solid lines. To fix the linetype legend set the breaks (and labels) so that only the benchmark lines are displayed in the legend. Additionally we have to do a hack via the `override.aes` argument of `guide_legend` to the colors to linetype legend:

Note: I also fixed the livetypes. I had chosen `"dashed"` but after a closer look IMHO it should be `22`.

```
library(ggplot2)

pal_lty <- rep(c("solid", "22"), 2)

names(pal_lty) <- c("model1.a_sc1", "model1.bench", "model2.a_sc1", "model2.bench")

ggplot(data = mydata2, aes(x = year)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = q1, ymax = q9, fill = model), linetype = 0, alpha = 0.2, na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = q3, ymax = q7, fill = model), linetype = 0, alpha = 0.2, na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_line(aes(
    x = year, y = q5,
    color = model,
    linetype = paste(model, scenario, sep = ".")
  ), size = 1.3) +
  scale_color_manual(values = col2) +
  scale_linetype_manual(
    values = pal_lty,
    breaks = c("model1.bench", "model2.bench"),
    labels = c("Bench_model1", "Bench_model2"),
    guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = col2))
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = col2f) +
  labs(y = "var [mg/l]", x = "", linetype = "Bench") +
  theme_light() +
  theme(
    text = element_text(size = 18),
    axis.text = element_text(colour = "black", size = 20),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 22)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Stefan, this helps me understand how ggplot works. I have edited my question with an image of how I would like it to plot. I regard the benchmark dashed lines as separate data that has to have separate legend section.

Comment: Hi Shajar. You are welcome. Based on your updated post I just made an edit to achieve that.